# How to treat a Linq to Entities query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, exception

I have this code:

```
    public article GetArticleByWebSite(string webSite)
    {
        using (var context = new ceopolandEntities())
        {
            return context.article.Where(a => a.WebSite == webSite).First();
        }
    }
```

What's the best way to check if article isn't empty before calling `First()`?

A try catch block or introduce a variable and check how many articles are there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `.FirstOrDefault();`. It will return `null` if nothing is found.